# Cannot Unlock System Settings 14.04

Tags: 14.04, time, system-settings

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Chromebook 14 using Crouton. I've gotten things setup and installed the programs I need. The time & date settings are using the wrong timezone though and when I go to system settings I can't change anything as it tells me to unlock first, all though I'm an administrator and the button is unclickable.

Here is a pic of my screen...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfI0z.jpg

What do I need to do to change this?

--- EDIT ---

I'm adding this edit as I've solved how to fix the incorrect date & time settings, but the question of how to unlock the System Settings still remain.

Since this is setup on a Chromebook using crouton many of the system operations are inherited/shared from Chrome OS. For instance none of your network connections are managed or shown in Ubuntu. When I put my Chromebook in developer mode it obviously resets these settings so I setup crouton/Ubuntu and had forgotten to go back and change the time in Chrome OS to my time zone.

When I realized this I logged out of Ubuntu, changed the time zone to my time and then ran the startunity command again to start up Ubuntu. The time is corrected now and that annoyance is gone.

Ultimately I'm not sure why it seems to lock some of these settings, and maybe it's only the ones inherited by Chrome OS, but nonetheless I halfway fixed the problem. I'm leaving this question open though if anyone as anything to offer as far as the root of the problem; locked system settings goes.

Comment: I notice something strange: under "last login", it says that user Benji logged in "Today, 9:26" whereas it ought to say "Logged in". Are you logged in as Benji? Or somehow as root?

Comment: @Jos I'm logged in as Benji, I know this because when I hit the power button at the top right it displays "Benji"